# how to get the date and time of the latest modified file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

so i got a folder containing multiple txt file for example: this is the path C:\folder

```
txt1.txt
txt2.txt
txt3.txt
```

each one is created at the same day but different time.
i need to output the date and time of latest date modified file in that folder using batch file

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output of the `DIR` command with a `FOR /F` command.

```
Pushd "c:\folder"
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /TW /OD *.txt') do SET "filedate=%%~tG"
popd
```